# Swift crashes - SIGABRT - Also how to track crashes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging, google-signin

I am completely new to Swift, Xcode and programming on Mac.

I have started working on some kind of app, and all I really did was add Firebase (Which worked), and then try to add Google Sign In. Nothing else exists really. So There really was a Google Sign In Button. I think the crash started happening when I connected a property to the Google Sign In Button.

Alas, I am new to this, and I don't even know how to debug properly. Can someone please be of assistant ?

My code :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool 
{
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FirebaseApp.configure()

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = 
        FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

        return true
}


override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self    
}
```

This is the property:

```
@IBOutlet weak var googleLoginButton: GIDSignInButton!
```

Comment: ok but also there is too many questions please search also for help please check your all view with outlet and action also try to debug and go to last line of code where you get crash

Comment: As I said, I do not really know Swift yet. I am learning. What is the Outlet ? And yeah, I just saw I have one, and it did cause the crash.

Comment: @IBOutlet weak var googleLoginButton: GIDSignInButton!

This is what I have. I changed the "!" to "?" and it doesn't crash any longer. But what did I do wrong ?

Comment: ? sign is used for optional declaration means if there is nil then thats ignore or ! is used like mandatory so thats crashes or if possible then try to learn language first then developement

Comment: Just tried again, and it still crashes.

Comment: please check your button outlet is set with storyboard or xib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: please do as in images]

[image]

And then try to run your project so you get that line where you app crashes

Comment: Thanks! :) Doing this just now

Comment: Ok, so now I have, under "All Exceptions" :

1) objc_exception_throw (in libabjc.A.dylib)
2) __cxa_throw in libc++abi.dylib

Comment: Kiran - I do not understand. What debug point ? I'm confused. If you can explain it in C# terms, that'd be excellent :)